# Как увеличить память в приложении для телефона

Tags: java, android

В Java есть аргументы выделения памяти для компьютеров или для устройств

```bash
java -Xmx 512m -Xms 512m
```

А можно выделить память для андроид приложения. Я слышал что-то про heap(куча). Был бы признателен если бы вы и про это рассказали

Comment: в манифесте largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В *Android* память делится на две области: *Java Heap* и *Native Heap*.

*Java Heap* относится к области памяти, где хранятся объекты *Java* и которой можно управлять. Для изменения можно использовать параметры в `build.gradle`:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Побольше можно в [документации](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory).